# Use terms in regex to extract unknown/proximity values?

Tags: sphinx

Say I use Sphinx to look for a term/pattern e.g.

```
(Cost|Price|Charge) Near\6 $<somevalue>
```

Where somevalue is an integer between say 1 and 6 digits? In regex I could do this with Groups and run the regex to return the `<somevalue>`. Is there any similar way to do this in Sphinx?

In other words for the string

```
at a cost of $300 each
```

$300 would be returned.

and for the string:

```
Price: $192.25
```

$192.25 would be returned

Essentially looking for a value but only when surrounded by a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no 'regex' style wildcards. Nothing to match only numbers.

You could add $ to charset_table, so its a word char, then enable prefix index or even infix indexing, and then could do

(Cost|Price|Charge) Near/6 $*

To get any. although toy might have to post filter in case it catches some that are not actully numeric.

Comment: Thanks but to be clear I am less concerned with the number match per se than returning whatever values is in the pattern. are you saying if I did the above the term that matched the * is what would be returned? Even if I did '(Cost|Price|Charge) Near/6 *'.  Basically looking to return a value using a pattern to extract it.

Comment: No sphinx wont give the actual match. Just the documents that match. Up to you to find the exact text in document, although the snippets / excerpts function could help